# refers to a type but its used as value here

Tags: typescript

How I can fix this error. 
I need to declare a variable of interface type in function

```
//interface     
export interface Activity {
        id: number;
        name: string;
    }

/*import statements are here*/

export class SelectActiivityComponent implements OnInit {
private activityList: Activity[];//its working 

 changeView(){
     activityList: Activity[];
//error here
//'Activity' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
}
....
....
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to do:

```
let activityList: Activity[];
```

Comment: i did but i cannot access properties of Activity now. like if i am trying to assign some like
let activitylist:Activity;
 activitylist.id="some numeric value"// then it gives error that its undefined

Comment: Are you looping through the array?

Comment: `activityList` is an array that contains `Activity` items. The array doesn't have `id` and `name` properties - only the elements in the array have those properties.

Comment: I declared one class variable like 
let activitylist: Activity; 
bit I cannot access properties from this object as it say undefined

Comment: `activitylist: Activity` doesn't make sense. An `Activity` is a single activity, it is not a list of activities. The latter would be represented by `activitylist: Activity[]`, and then you add `Activity` items to that list like `activitylist.push({ id: 1, name: 'name'})` and then loop through the list to access each activity.